# Какие файлы проекта толкать в удаленный репозиторий?

Tags: git, laravel

Разрабатываю локально на Laravel, периодически толкаю в удаленный репозиторий. Есть вопросы:

1. Что бы вы посоветовали писать в файл `README.MD` (сейчас там описание
   фреймворка `Laravel`)? Краткое описание проекта или полноценную
   документацию?
2. Внутри дистрибутива `Laravel` есть файл `.gitignore`, в нем, среди
   прочего, указана папка `vendor`, т.е. в удаленный репозиторий она не
   попадает.  Я работаю по такой схеме: разрабатываю локально, толкаю в
   remote, потом оттуда забираю на `dev.myproject.com` и показываю шефу.
   Когда забираю, папки `vendor`, естественно, нет, приходиться ее туда
   заливать отдельно, по старинке, по ftp. Меня это смущает, все так
   делают?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) В README.md должно быть кратко описано о проекте и о том, как его "разворачивать". Также неплохо указать линценцию и линцензии на используемые библиотеки.

2) Обычно папка vendor не изменяется ручками. Поэтому и не нужно ее пихать в репозиторий. А для управление используется composer. Это его задача все скачать и настроить. А что бы на продашине все было хорошо и просто, обычно делают скрипты "сборки". И можно настроить эти скрипты срабатывать по git push в master. Как результат все будет автоматом разворачиваться.

Comment: Спасибо. У меня сайт на виртуальном хостинге, там только git, composer нет, и скрипты там не запустить.

Comment: если там есть git и Вы уго можете запустить, значит скорее всего у Вас есть доступ к консоли (например по http). А значит, можно запускать скрипты на баше или на том же php. На крайний случай, можно делать себе скрипт, потокрый потом будет с браузера запускаться - это уже сложно запретить сделать. Где то так работает инсталляция популярных joomla, drupal и подобных.